# my Mac Pro Yosemite randomly restarts

Tags: macos, mac

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, late 2011)
When I upgraded to Yosemite, it was fine until a month ago, then there is no day that my computer does not restart/freeze randomly. I am really tired of it, so any help is really appreciated. 
What I have done? Basically everything:

- Start up in safe mode
- Reset parameter random-access memory (PRAM)
- Repair the startup disk/ disk permissions,
- I tried to use Apple Hardware Test, but I get error -D200 or something like that
  basically I get some error like http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553

After all that I did, I even clean installed Yosemite (I mean, I formatted my disk and then installed again) it was okay for a week but then started again.

Can you please share your knowledge with me?

Here was the panic I just received

```
Anonymous UUID:       BD73F3E5-FAC9-A729-5331-7A57641F2024

Sun Feb 22 12:31:41 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff800b5fae93): "TLB invalidation IPI timeout: " "CPU(s) failed to respond to interrupts, unresponsive CPU bitmap: 0x40, NMIPI acks: orig: 0x0, now: 0x0"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.10.72/osfmk/x86_64/pmap.c:2484
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff811740b030 : 0xffffff800b52fe41 
0xffffff811740b0b0 : 0xffffff800b5fae93 
0xffffff811740b140 : 0xffffff800b601183 
0xffffff811740b230 : 0xffffff800b601e55 
0xffffff811740b290 : 0xffffff800b5b079a 
0xffffff811740b3a0 : 0xffffff800b5a697c 
0xffffff811740b3d0 : 0xffffff800b5c8b81 
0xffffff811740b410 : 0xffffff800b7291fe 
0xffffff811740b420 : 0xffffff7f8d33638d 
0xffffff811740b560 : 0xffffff800b78293d 
0xffffff811740b5c0 : 0xffffff800b729363 
0xffffff811740b710 : 0xffffff800b735d8e 
0xffffff811740b8a0 : 0xffffff800b738310 
0xffffff811740ba60 : 0xffffff800b734632 
0xffffff811740bd20 : 0xffffff800b93fd48 
0xffffff811740bdb0 : 0xffffff800b766491 
0xffffff811740be50 : 0xffffff800b9ebefa 
0xffffff811740bef0 : 0xffffff800b9ec06e 
0xffffff811740bf50 : 0xffffff800ba4b386 
0xffffff811740bfb0 : 0xffffff800b636e86 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.BootCache(35.0)[D0F8226C-C576-3842-8BBE-447477780234]@0xffffff7f8d333000->0xffffff7f8d33cfff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: CalendarAgent

Mac OS version:
14C109

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DCF5C2D5-16AE-37F5-B2BE-ED127048DFF5
Kernel slide:     0x000000000b200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800b400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800b300000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 55475585264
last loaded kext at 45111904875: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f8d3fa000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.20
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.20
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.20
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.20
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.15.5
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.3.2f6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.8.6
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    1.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.3
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   910.26.12
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.25
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.1d38
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.8.6
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.3.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.10.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.5 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS727575A9E362, 750,16 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but if Apple Hardware Test is giving an error, I'd say you have a hardware fault and need to get it repaired.

Comment: I did not get error after running the test. I simply cannot connect the Mac Pro by holding option +D , it takes forever or at least half an hour then says something like 1005D error

Comment: 'something like' gives us no clue whatsoever. & what's opt/d supposed to do? Hardware test is just d

Comment: @Tetsujin when i restart the mac and only hold D, nothing happens but when i hold option and D it goes to the first step to AHT, it connects to internet but I got this error apple.com support 2002D error

Comment: that's a connectivity error, judging from Google. Are you using wifi? If so, try wiring up.

Comment: Try uninstalling any plug-ins or other enhancement software from manufacturers other than Apple.                                 If you recently updated OS X or an app, plug-ins and other software that worked in the past may no longer be compatible. Also read the manufacturer’s documentation (including Read Me notes) to be sure the software is compatible with your version of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've had that happen, a machine shutting itself down or restarting, it has meant logic board is going bad.

Comment: what would you do to solve it? I even downgraded my Yosemite but I am still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have had very good luck with the Yosemite Beta program, each release so improved upon the first disastrous official Yosemite release ... I back up my User folder and just download and install, and drag my stuff back (from USB external) - simple enough, makes more sense than trying to trace a lot of the glitches.

But I do think you've got a hardware problem, and if you don't have Applecare, you might want an independent Mac repair outfit, depending on where you live, to check it out. Not inexpensive, a new motherboard. But it happens.